# My app is crashing iOS 5! How can I get an iOS 5 app when Xcode/SDK is still beta?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, sdk

I just got an email from a user that my app is crashing on iOS 5. I haven't downloaded the beta xcode and ios 5 because it is just that - beta - and I can't release an app on it. I have an update that is time sensitive that is just about ready to go out, and now this..

How can I get my app ready for iOS 5 when it is still beta? If I download the latest (beta) SDK, xcode - can I even build and submit my app from that?

Every time I do an 'upgrade' I end up losing my current SDK/xCode because of no room on the computer. What can I do to keep xCode 4 and still get my app iOS safe - right away??

Comment: A beta is available for exactly this purpose: Testing and preparing a fix before release. The reason you're even asking this question is that you don't have enough room on your computer to install two versions at the same time. That's a hardware problem. Fix that. Waiting for release day to do regression tests will cost you users.

Comment: Thanks nschum. That actually helps. I didn't realize that I could actually run two versions of xcode at once. I didn't install the beta because I knew I could not submit from it. I am learning more every day. I am working on my hardware issue and will make sure to do things the right way from now on. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean:
http://www.macrumors.com/2011/10/04/apple-asking-developers-to-submit-ios-5-apps-ahead-of-october-12th-release/

Obviously, Apple has an interest in getting stable apps and release the necessary tools weeks ago to devs. Xcode 4.2 came out yesterday for the general public, so you should be able to do what is needed to get your app iOS5 ready. Xcode 4.2is not beta. iOS5 is not a beta. It is out there running on devices.

Comment: Crazy - I had been checking often for it to come out and just stopped a few days ago, stupidly thinking I would be okay. Oh well, it's gonna be a long night. Thanks for your help. That's good news at least..

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you, iOS 5 came out yesterday.

Make sure you have iTunes 10.5, and your iDevice will be able to update to iOS 5.

As for Xcode, you will have to find some more space. You will not have a problem with building and submitting your app as long as you are not using any functions that become depreciated in iOS 5.

Good luck, and get coding!

Comment: Yeah, it's better that I catch it now at least. Thanks for the encouraging words.